# How do I make "gather" object, place its self in the text, the same way as an equation object?

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath

Assuming the amsmath package is installed. I found a difference between the way that an equation object and a gather object is embedded within the text.

If an equation is beneath a line of text that does not extend as far to the right as the equation. Then the equation is placed higher up for asphetic reasons like so:

---

```
Hello there this is some text, blah, blah,  
blah, blah  
              a+b=c  

Some more text, hello
```

---

Or if the text goes beyond the equation, like so:

---

```
Hello there this is some text, blah, blah,
blah, blah, blah, blah

              a+b=c

Some more text, hello
```

---

If gather is used, then the gather object is placed a certain distance beneath the last line of text, regardless of it's extent across the page.

I would like gather to align equations in the same way as equation objects but this isn't as simple as using a permanent vspace{} command to push text up as it's need will be depend on the final layout of the text.

Can any one help? maybe this is even a bug to be resolved. by the ams group.

Thanks

I have prepared an example latex document here: http://pastebin.com/EUKyNi2A

Comment: I seem to recall reading that this is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

How about doing

```
\begin{equation}
     \begin{gathered}
          1+1=2
     \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

It is more typing, but it will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Jan, it does work... I'm still holding out for a better one as the extra typing is a bit enoying and also I make some use of the \displaybreak[] command in my work, which will not function in an alligned object. I'm guessing there are some other reasons why one might choose a gather object over a gathered within an equation which I have not reallised yet.

Comment: One reason is that amsmath + hyperref + equation environment can sometimes produce very bad spacing. Personally, I use `fleqn` option and use only amsmath environments, not equation.

Comment: I just ran into this question. It seems that the combination `equation/split` does still produce too much vertical spacing, while `gathered` and `aligned` work OK.

Answer (score 4):

The [`nccmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nccmath) package helps to correct amsmath's spacing. Load it and write `\useshortskip` if required. This command forces using the short skip in the next displayed formula. Such corrections should be done when preparing the final version.

```
\usepackage{nccmath}
...
% short text
\useshortskip
\begin{gather}
...
\end{gather}
```

For those, who would like to test, here's a minimal example fixing the code of the questioner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\useshortskip
Some words from my memory... I've seen things you people wouldn't believe.
Attack ships on fire\ldots
\useshortskip
\begin{gather}
a+b=c
\end{gather}
I watched `C' beams glisten in the dark, near the Tanhauser gate.

\bigskip

Some words from my memory... I've seen things you people wouldn't believe.
Attack ships on fire of\ldots
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
I watched `C' beams glisten in the dark, near the Tanhauser gate.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove `\useshortskip` and replace `nccmath` by `amsmath` to see the original problem:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution Stefan. I'm still hoping for the elusive "make the dammed thing just work" type solution.